# Datepicker Jqueryui no funciona en asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, jquery-ui

Saqué un ejemplo de un tutorial, lo puse se Sublime Text y usando el xampp lo probé y funciona el datepicker, sin embargo, en asp.net mvc, no

_Layout

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Nombre de aplicación", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Acerca de", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contacto", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Index

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="https://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hice lo que pediste, sin embargo no funciona. Agrego captura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

_Layout

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    

    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
    </script>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Nombre de aplicación", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Acerca de", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contacto", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

no es una buena práctica colocar los js en el `<HEAD>` de tu página, ya que retrasa el tiempo de respuesta, osea que hasta que no carguen estos archivos js, no podrás ver el contenido de tu página. Puedes colocar estos ficheros abajo justo después de:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

y antes de :

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

lo otro a verificar es que no estés llamando a 2 ficheros Jquery, pues en las línea antes descritas se llama a un bundle el cual inyecta Jquery. Verifica en las herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador, en al pestaña network que no estés cargando jquery más de una vez.

Y el punto más importante y el cual puede ser el motivo de ke no te funcione el datepicker es que estas renderizando la vista Index dentro del Layout después de cargar los js. por lo que deberías agregar el siguiente código en tu vista index.

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#datepicker').datepicker();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Vicente, hice los cambios pero no funciona, ¿me podrías decir por favor qué debo cambiar? o si tienes por ahí un ejemplo que funcione...

Answer (score 0):

Me funcionó con Bootstrap

```
<input type="date" id="fechaInicio" name="fechaInicio" class="Filtros form-control input-sm" />
```

Y para que reciba la fecha al editar

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FechaInicio, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "Filtros form-control input-sm", type = "date" })
```

Comment: En ese caso no está funcionando jquery datepicker, sino el datepicker del navegador. Al definir el tipo de campo es date, los navegadores modernos como chrome o firefox te generan un datepiker. El inconveniente es que cada navegador tiene su estilo. Prueba ejecutar la app en otro navegador para que veas de lo que te hablo

Comment: mmm.... Entonces hay que hacer una adptación para que funcione en varios navegadores? si es así, como se haría @Vicente ?

Comment: No hay que hacer nada, simplemente el campo de tipo date será mostrado como un datepicker y varía su estilo según el navegador.